# Is there a hard limit on the number of devices that can connect to Google's services such as Gmail, Drive, etc?

Tags: google, google-workspace

We have a shared inbox and wanted to know if there is a limitation of how many devices can connect to a given mail box or Google Drive account.

For example, as we have over 100 people in a call centre, will this be an issue if all of them accessed the shared inbox at the same time via their browser, mobile, tablets, etc.?

Comment: @BloodPhilia - Thanks. The reason I posted it here is because it does have to do with computer software and hardware i.e. the number of devices that can connect to a given service as well as the number of connections a given app can have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gmail there is an IMAP Connection limit of [15 simultaneous connections.](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/97150?hl=en)  Web browser users **should** be ok, but tablet and phone users may  receive the error message, 'Too many simultaneous connections' and then have imap be subsequently blocked.

Do you also want to allow the same level of access to the account to all users?  Someone could get wily and change the password.....

Have you considered a distribution list/group using gmail?  This would require separate accounts for your call center users.

As far as google drive goes, there [are limits on connections](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494827) but that applies to sharing items in one google drive account, and collaborating with others.

Comment: @G Koe - Thanks. Do all Google apps utilize IMAP when attempting to access emails? I was under the impression it would be some other protocol. For example what does the Gmail app use to connect to Gmail?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey the android/ios apps use "google apps sync"  which is actually a combination of Imap, CalDAV, and CardDAV. http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/09/a-new-way-to-sync-google-contacts.html

Comment: If you hit the IMAP limit, The solution is to manually sign out of sessions.  You do this by logging into your gmail account via a web browser.  Then at the bottom you will see in small print "Last account activity: xxx minutes ago at IP 999.999.999.999."  Next to that is a DETAILS link.  Click on that.  Now you will see all the IP's that make up the connection.  Click on the button Sign Out all other sessions and wala you've freed up connections.
hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting up a collaborative inbox in Google Groups - http://www.googlegooru.com/how-to-setup-a-collaborative-inbox-in-google-groups/

This would allow an administrator to manage members' access to the group content, permissions for posting, etc. rather than giving every member the same permissions (which could be a problem if you're giving 100+ people access).

Also, no problems with simultaneous connections since it's a Group and not a user account.